# Determining handle type in GDI+

Tags: gdi+, autohotkey

Say I have an arbitrary GDI+ handle, how can I determine the underlying type of GDI+ object it represents? Brush, Pen, Image, Matrix, etc?

I have searched online but can only find examples for GDI, but nothing for GDI+, does GDI+ have such a facility?

EDIT: Just to note, I am not using C++, so I do not have access to any language-specific features to determine the object type. I am creating a GDI+ wrapper for AutoHotkey, so am pretty much limited to functions in DLLs.

Comment: I am not familiar with Autohotkey. You should post some sample code. If you are using Gdi+ Flat APIs then I think there is no way.

Comment: Yes, I am limited to using the Flat API, or other API calls from DLLs. AHK is an interpreted language, and has some limitations, not sure what code examples I could post as the code itself isn't really relevant. I do believe you are right, however, in that there doesn't seem to be an official way to determine the type of a GDI+ handle from just the handle itself, outside of using the "typeid" operator as you've mentioned.

Comment: Do these objects have unique methods or attributes? Having a quick look at the docs it seems that a Pen has the attribute `PenType` which none of the other classes have. May be a bit tedious to create a set of rules in order to identify an object by its attributes or methods, but better than nothing I suppose.

Comment: The problem is that GDI+ is wrapped up by Microsoft into a collection of C++ classes, however, the only access I have is via the flat API. So my pen "object" is really just a simple handle which I have to pass around to the various pen APIs. I have wrapped all of this up myself into AutoHotkey classes, so essentially providing the same type of system for AHK as Microsoft does for C++. The one case where I needed to be able to determine the type of object was for brushes, and surprisingly there actually is an API to return the type of brush... just no API for generic GDI+ objects themselves!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator

Example:

```
Gdiplus::Brush *brush;
Gdiplus::Pen *pen;
Gdiplus::Image *image;
Gdiplus::Matrix *matrix;

cout << "brush: " << typeid(brush).name() << '\n';
cout << "pen: " << typeid(pen).name() << '\n';
cout << "image: " << typeid(image).name() << '\n';
cout << "matrix: " << typeid(matrix).name() << '\n';
```

output:

> ```
> brush: class Gdiplus::Brush *
> pen: class Gdiplus::Pen *
> image: class Gdiplus::Image *
> matrix: class Gdiplus::Matrix *
> ```

Comment: That would be helpful if I were using C++, I am in the process of creating a GDI+ wrapper for AutoHotkey so unfortunately I do not have access to the typeid operator. I was hoping for an API call of some sort I could call via AHKs DllCall function, but I have not had much luck there. Thank you for your answer, I should have been more clear which environment I was using! While your answer was not what I needed, it is very appropriate for C++ users so I voted it up! :)